# Testing a String from a Textfield in jQuery and Execute a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have to test a string from an asp.net vb Textfield with jQuery and execute a Bootstrap Modal yes or no. This is the code that might come close, I spent several hours gathering the pieces from the internet. The purpose is: If AB in txtOne is valid then show modalZK.

```
<script>
    $("#txtOne").blur(function () {

        function validate() {
            var one = document.getElementById('<%=txtOne.ClientID%>').value;
            if (one.slice(0,2) == "AB") 
            {
                ('#modalZK').modal('show');
            }};
        ;
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    $("#txtOne").blur(function () {
        // remove function declaration `validate`
        var one = document.getElementById('<%=txtOne.ClientID%>').value;
        if (one.slice(0,2) == "AB") 
        {
            // missing jQuery `$` 
            $('#modalZK').modal('show');
        }
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script>
    $("#txtOne").blur(function () {
            var one = document.getElementById('<%=txtOne.ClientID%>').value;
            if (one.slice(0,2) == "AB") 
            {
                $('#modalZK').modal('show');
            }         
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It only works for a Textbox with no Postback. Is it possible to work for a Textbox with Postback?

Comment: You could consider saving the Textbox's value in a hidden field.